# SingleTask Activity , SharedPreference value not getting updated

Tags: java, android

I have an activity that is set singletask  in Manifest.

Now i have stored some value in sharedpreference let say "theme_value" = 0;
Now when i change the value on sharedpreference  let say "theme_value" = 3;

When i am trying to get the value, in a normal activty i am getting the result. as "theme_value" = 3,
but  getting theme_value = 0 in activity that is single task.

Can anyone please tell me why this happening, and how to resolve it.

Comment: Please make sure you are using same spelling in both places ? Preferences does not affect either your activity is singletask or anything.

Comment: @khurram spelling is same in both places, when i quit the app and run again value gets right there after

Comment: did you use editor.commit(); method and all other things properly

Comment: @khurram yes that is done